# REST performing an action

Tags: rest

I'm designing a REST API where I need to give the clients the ability to copy resources.
Say for example you have the following resource: customer/{customerno}/address

And you will provide the client with functionallity for copying the address to shippingaddress.
I could do like this: customer/{customerno}/address/copytoshipping

But then it would be RPC and not REST. What is the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: It is not acceptable to place the work on the client side. The server needs to perform the copy. I want my clients to be as thin as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Does that have to be in the REST API? The client could just GET the representation of the (billing?) address and PUT it to the shipping address. Yes, you might well hide the details of that in your client-side code (that seems very reasonable to me) but there's no particular reason to clutter the REST interface with special operations to do the copying.

Comment: It is not acceptable in this case to put the work on the client. What is the best way to do this on the server?

Answer (score 1):

GET the address using Rel="CustomerAddress"

POST using Rel="CustomerShippingAddress" example URL customer/{customerno}/address/shipping

Comment: How does the `rel=…` map to the POST? I was under the impression that the _rel_ation is only specified in the HTML (or via equivalent suitably-namespaced node in XML).

Comment: Really the rel and the POST have no relation. The Rel just shows that there should be a shipping address resource that can be worked on just like the address one. So it could support GET, PUT, POST and DELETE like the other resource.  My post was intended to show that the shipping address was just another resource and so to copy the original address, you just need to post it to a different REL.

Comment: Ah, so you're talking about supplying a description of the subresources. That's OK.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach could be:

- Expose a resource for "customer address" (as you stated above)

  `GET /customer/{number}/address`
- Expose a resource for "customer shipping address"
  fetch:

  `GET /customer/{number}/shipping-address`
- update with actual address:

  ```
  PUT /customer/{number}/shipping-address
  Content-Type: application/xml  
  (xml/json of a single address)
  ```
- update using a URI pointer to another address

  ```
  PUT /customer/number/shipping-address HTTP/1.1
  Content-Type: application/atom+xml
  (xml/json of an atom:link with href pointer to main address ('/customer/123/address')
  ```

Perhaps more complex than you want but puts the copy burden on the server rather than the client.

Comment: The last one doesn't need atom in the mix: the XLink spec is suitable too.